# Can't fix the width of popup element (colorbox jquery override)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal-6, colorbox

I have the following code on my site that's supposed to show a popup window

```
<span class="fbridge-signup-form" data-widget-id="21378"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var secure = ("https:" == document.location.protocol);
  var fb_js_host = (secure ? "https://www.fanbridge.com" : "http://widget-platform.fanbridge.com");
  window._FBRIDGE_WIDGETS_HOST = fb_js_host; var p, s, id = 'fbridge-widgetjssdk-v1';
  p = document.createElement('script'); p.id = id; p.type = 'text/javascript'; p.async = true;
  p.src = (secure ? "https://ssl.fbridgecdn.net" : "http://static.fbridgecdn.net") + '/js/fb/widget/v1/platform.js?_=' + ((new Date()).getTime());
  s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(p, s);

})();
</script>
```

It works fine, but the problem is that there's some setting with lightboxes on my Drupal site that makes this window of a smaller width and height than the actual content inside.

I tried getting the element with `getElementByClassName` or writing the `width` and `height`parameters into the style property of `fbridge-signup-form` but it didn't work out.

Do you know what I could do to force it to be a certain width and height? Say 480px by 400px?

You can check the actual page on http://waytorussia.net/Moscow/Intro.html (it has a cookie set to show only once).

**UPDATE: maybe it's possible to use another kind of popup so this one is not overridden by my other settings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Vincent G and @KyleT for their help I found that I had to edit the CSS styles for colorbox module.

```
#cboxLoadedContent iframe{display:block; min-width: 480px; min-height: 400px; border:0;}
```

and

```
#colorbox{min-width: 480px !important; min-height: 400px !important; }
```

in the `colorbox.css` file which was part of my Drupal installation.

After that the widget was loading fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML source, the element you should resize is (id) cboxContent.
But the black frame around it doesn't seem "ready" (from an HTML/Css point of view) to be resized.

See the screenshot here:

[image: Resizing div 'cboxContent']

I resized it 400x400.

**EDIT** -
By resizing all the appropriate elements, you can manage to get what you want. Here's an example done manually:
[image: Resized picture 2]

Just inspect the element (right-click > Inspect) with a modern browser, and look at the divs that you need to resize on load (with JavaScript).

Comment: Maybe I can use another way to call this popup?

Comment: I would personally (I think) do the job (popup + css) myself. Do you think you can use some existing libraries to save some time?

Comment: Sure I tried a few, but they would have very bad styling (popup appearing somewhere it shouldn't be) so there's always a conflict. It'd be great just to find a popup that works and can load an external page but only to first-time visitors (so with a cookie). Thanks!

Comment: Look at my Edit ;). You need 3 minutes to inspect all the elements ID's and 5 to write  the javascript which resize eveything.

Take care: there are 4 corners, 4 borders, a global wrapper, the content, and a kind of wrapper for the content. You don't need to touch change the corners. Just resize the wrapper, the borders, and the content.

Comment: I think your script already uses the "colorbox" module that KyleT advised, because the HTML is the exact same.

Comment: This will work but keep in mind that if you want readers to be able to view the modal on smartphones, tablets etc of smaller size view then this will not scale well.

Comment: I fully agree! Yet I think this kind of popup shouldn't be imposed to a visitor using a smartphone / tablet. At least, a "smaller" version, lighter, should be displayed to smartphone/tablet users.

Pure UI/UX point of view, absolutely personal.

Answer (score 1):

i opened your page in Firefox with the developer tools to see how things work width and height wise and the results are interesting.

[image]

Basically the frame of the lightbox is made up of numerous divs all seem to be hard coded to a specific width and height. When you hover over the inner content using the inspector tool you can see that the inner content is actually the correct width and height but the container ( your collection of divs is not )

Try expanding the height and width of the container divs using css maybe??

I wouldnt have used this as answer but unfortunately i cant provide screenshots using just the comments section to my knowledge.

**To see the image at full screen open it in a new tab.**

For a good alternative try [colorbox](http://plugins.jquery.com/colorbox/) its a great JQuery modal plugin that can be used for just about anything.

Demos are [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/). Have a look at inline HTML example it seems to be similar to what you need.

Comment: You think I could just use another way to call this popup?

Comment: Well I personally would remove the border and build it myself using JQuery but Is it safe to say that this is not your script?

Comment: Was there any of other source that came with the JS script? like a css file?

Comment: No, the CSS is loaded on that html page that opens. It's just that my Drupal site has a special setting for lightboxes somewhere I guess... I'll check that css out...

Comment: As Vincent G has pointed out the issue is most likely #cboxContent element not being resized correctly however the frame has also not been designed to accomodate anything more than a fixed width or height. Ill see if i can find a good alternative for you.